# Should I implement my own deque class using vectors to improve performance accroding to my usage or keep using std::deque?

Tags: c++, vector, time-complexity, deque

I am working on a code where I maintain 32-64 deques using vector of deques. Each of these deque accomodate around 150-200 elements.Moreover, Once I am done filling all these deques I have to clear them using clear() function which I believe also takes time. I am repeating this process for thousands of times. So, is it better to implement my own deque class using vector? In this case I won't have the overhead of clear() the deque as I could just simply reset the front and back pointer. Can I expect any performance imporvement?
Edit: Later one I have to merge those deques i.e. 2 deques into one using outplace place. For that I have to write a code so any suggestion how should I implement my deque class (like by using two vectors for front and back)?

Comment: What is stopping you from trying it and seeing if it improves performance?

Comment: Have you profiled your code and proven that `clear()` is real bottleneck?

Comment: Actually, I profiled my code but I had a hard time understanding the output. I am trying to do that. Moreover, I have two merge two deques so any suggest regarding how should I implement my deque class like two vector for front and back?

Comment: If you cannot understand output of profiling can you really implement a better version of `std::deque`? Advise to seek solution to the problem you have in another way.